# How to "Identify name and father name from text with out keyword" in java or android?

Tags: java, android, regex, libraries

I have 4 lines of string in array list, which includes name father name dob and some alphanumeric number. This data comes in random like sometime name can come at the top, sometime dob can come at the top.

```
JHON PAUL
ROBERT PAUL
16/06/1983
ABCDR2445A
```

I want to show this data in sorted way with name first then father's name then dob then alphanumeric code. This data don't have any key word only values. How to do it ?

First, I have tried sorting the array list with alphabets at the top numbers after that and last alphanumeric code. The problem is sometime it puts the name at top sometime father's name at the top.
Second, I used regex to get the name, dob and alphanumeric code.It works fine for dob and alphanumeric code. But for name and father's name it get confused.
Thirdly I used if and break statement. Like when ever the compiler gets the first name then it should break. It did not worked.

```java
ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){
 // i got stuck here what to do?

}
```

expected result should be

```
NAME
FATHER NAME
DOB
CODE
```

Comment: How would you recognize which name is which?

Comment: not possible without key or order

Comment: It _might_ be possible to detect name, but I don't think it would be possible to distinguish between the father and child name.  You would need to give us more information about how to tell them apart.

Comment: which in your example is the name and which ism the father name, and how did you know it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I don't know it. The data is coming randomly from document scanner.

Comment: then how can **we** know? Please then first find that out before asking.

Comment: that is exactly my question "how can we know?"

Comment: that question does not relate to development at all. Don't ask us how to differ between father's name and son's name.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to get the data is respective key for each value like this:

```
"data": {
    "name": "abcd",
    "dob": "01/08/2000",
    "fathername": "shdjs",
    "alphavalue": "ABCDR2445A",
}
```

Since you are not getting data like this, you can split the string with space. You can use String format your dob and alphanumeric but it is highly imposible to differentiate name and fathername as both are nearly same formatted string.

Comment: Its a random data . So I can't be sure wether the name will have three letters or two. or father name will have three or two.

Answer (score 0):

You can force user to enter sons name in three word that is : [first name] [middle name] [last name] and father name as [first name] [last name] and then can decide who is son and who is father by checking whether son's middle name equals fathers first name

Comment: The problem is I have no control on the data . They are coming from document scan. which doesn't include keywords.

Comment: Please add this to your question's description, so that the other will understand it. Also describe what kind of document you are scanning

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is some update. Its not the perfect but will do. I searched for date once i got the date I removed it from the list. Then I searched for alphanumeric code, once I got the code I removed it from the list. So now I am left with two names. Now the problem is I don't know which one is father's and which is. So I made a list view to put both the name.